# Problem with iPhone starting up completely

Tags: ios, restore

I went to turn on my phone and I got a black screen with a circle going round and round. The phone will not turn off and will not respond when pushing the home button. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you hear alert sounds and/or charging sounds?

Comment: What phone do you have?

Answer (score 1):

The steps to fix any iOS device that won't boot fully are the same and pretty easy to accomplish following Apple's support on how to restore a device.

Consider trying to make a backup or check if you have your data (programs, contacts, settings, photos) either synchronized or backed up before you restore - that irreversibly deletes everything you put on your phone as the first step of the restore:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252

At the bottom of that article are several that might need to be epxplored if the normal restore fails, up to and including calling for a hardware repair to an authorized (or unauthorized if you prefer) repair shop.